# PowerShell: A drive with the name '@{Path=C' does not exist

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to search through a directory of files and pull out all the file paths that have the pattern.  Then loop through each file and search for another pattern of text.  It works if I manually do:

`Select-String -Path "C:\inetpub\mailroot\Badmail-Archive\003c908531613052021000000A2.BAD" -Pattern ('Final-Recipient') | Select -ExpandProperty line`

It does not if I do it in the loop:

```
$FileList = Get-ChildItem  "C:\inetpub\mailroot\Badmail-Archive" -Filter *.BAD | Select-String -Pattern 'Diagnostic-Code: smtp;550 5.1.1' | Select-Object Path
$FileList += Get-ChildItem  "C:\inetpub\mailroot\Badmail-Archive" -Filter *.BAD | Select-String -Pattern 'Diagnostic-Code: smtp;550 5.1.2' | Select-Object Path
$FileList += Get-ChildItem  "C:\inetpub\mailroot\Badmail-Archive" -Filter *.BAD | Select-String -Pattern 'Diagnostic-Code: smtp;550 5.2.1' | Select-Object Path



foreach($filepath in $FileList) { 
   $BADSearch = Select-String -Path $filepath -Pattern ('Final-Recipient') | Select -ExpandProperty    line
   $eMailAddress = $BADSearch.Split(";")[1]
   echo "File Path:  $filepath"
   echo $eMailAddress
}
```

```
File Path:  C:\inetpub\mailroot\Badmail-Archive\003c908531613052021000000A2.BAD

Select-String : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name '@{Path=C' does not exist.
At C:\Scripts\BadEmails-SQLGenerator.ps1:46 char:14
+ ... BADSearch = Select-String -Path $filepath -Pattern ('Final-Recipient' ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (@{Path=C:String) [Select-String], DriveNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DriveNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SelectStringCommand
```

Comment: You are treating the response from the `Get-ChildItem` call as if it's a string.  It is not.  You need to pass in a proper path as a string to `Select-String` like `Select-String -Path $filepath.FullName # ...`

Comment: @MaximilianBurszley I just got on that path and was trying $filepath.toString.  It's saying Path is empty.  On the GCI should I just do something like Format-Table and then do the $filepath.FullName down below?

Comment: Oh, I didn't scroll right to see you were using `Select-Object` and doing other filters already... That is another part of your problem

Comment: @MaximilianBurszley I think I got it with your answer!

Comment: I removed the `Select-Object` from the GCI's and then just used `$filepath.Path`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is with treating any arbitrary object as if it's a string.  `Select-String` expects a `string` instance for the `Path` parameter, but you're passing it the resulting `MatchInfo` object returned from the previous `Select-String` call.

You'll need to tease out the path by selecting the `.Path` member from the previous command output:

```
Select-String -Path $filepath.Path # ...
```